# UV Unmapping Specific Mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh, uv

I'm trying to add an image to the top side of my cube. I have marked the seams and unwrapped it, and when I choose to add the image to the cube, it gets wrapped up on all sides, rather than the specific location. How can I fix this?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: there are several solutions, if you only want to show the picture on the top face you can simply give a material to the top face and another one to the other faces... if you want to keep the same material on all the faces, for example because you want to use the same red background, just scale down the UV of these faces in the UV Editor so that you only have red

Comment: Thank you for your information, it worked out well.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several solutions, if you only want to show the picture on the top face you can simply give a material to the top face and another one to the other faces... if you want to keep the same material on all the faces, for example because you want to use the same red background, just scale down the UV of these faces in the *UV Editor* so that you only have red